# How to simulate slow DVD drive?

Tags: macos, performance-testing, iso, dmg, dvd

Does anyone know any feasible ways to simulate a slow DVD drive, e.g. over a mounted DMG/ISO image?

The goal is to program against a slow drive, thus a simulation requirement. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Update: again, the goal would be to simulate a slow I/O process. Tools like Network Conditioner or Charles do not provide a solution unfortunately. trickle is out of date and no more actively developed :(

Comment: why are you concerned about this in the first place?

Comment: Explained in the 2nd sentence. Does the concern deserve a downvote? IMO, it's a perfectly valid request. Tools like Network Conditioner or Charles exist.

Comment: the downvote is because theres no sign of effort or research. my concern is not addressed by your second sentence. why is your code dependent on a certain I/O throughput?

Comment: Effort of research is extensive. I wouldn't post here and sit back waiting if someone actually comes back with a solution. If I had found a solution, I wouldn't have posted! Couldn't you imagine a scenario where software runs entirely from removable media?

Comment: @DanielA.White - "why are you concerned about this in the first place?" - What sort of comment is this? If it doesn't interest you, move along.

Comment: @BrettHale i'm trying to see if there's a hidden problem that could be solved without being dependent on disc speed.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately not Daniel. I have to stream from a DVD to an AIR app and that is unfortunately set in stone by the business model. So my hands are tied to tech solutions. I'd like to get a decent platform so I can fire a debugger on that simulation and profile the performance to see what classes perform slowest. Something along the lines.

Comment: So the I/O involved is both reading data (that you will stream) **and** page-in of executable pages?  Also what APIs are you using to read your data? (If Objective-C then some runtime twizzling could be used).

Comment: You could also use a sort of self made library with a configurable KB/s output given a stream. You just call wait in the library logic depending how many KB/s you want and get already on the stream. Of course it should notify you, should you ask for more throughput than the Stream itself gives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With hdiutil, you could mount a disk image over a specially crafted HTTP server, but you do not control the OS cache and I/O slowness would not be fine-grained. I would suggest two non-network solutions.

### Inserting slowness in I/O system calls

You could do slow-down I/O system calls, for example through `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES`. This approach is quite easy and this is what I would try first.

You simply create a library with `read(2)` and `pread(2)` implementations like:

```
/* slow.c */
#define SLEEP_TIMESPEC {0, 25000000} // 25ms
ssize_t
read(int fildes, void *buf, size_t nbyte) {
    struct timespec s = SLEEP_TIMESPEC;
    (void) nanosleep(&s, NULL);
    return (ssize_t) syscall(SYS_read, fildes, buf, nbyte);
}

ssize_t
pread(int d, void *buf, size_t nbyte, off_t offset) {
    struct timespec s = SLEEP_TIMESPEC;
    (void) nanosleep(&s, NULL);
    return (ssize_t) syscall(SYS_pread, d, buf, nbyte, offset);
}
```

You might also need to implement `readv(2)`. You simply need to compile this C code as a shared library and set `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES` to load this library before running your program. You will probably also need to define `DYLD_FORCE_FLAT_NAMESPACE`. See `dyld(1)`.

```
clang -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -shared -Wall slow.c -o slow.dylib
```

(The library is compiled universally, as the AIR app I had on disk was actually i386, not x86_64).

To test the library, simply do:

```
env DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=slow.dylib DYLD_FORCE_FLAT_NAMESPACE=1 cat slow.c
```

You might want to try with values higher than 25ms for `cat`, e.g. 1 second which can be inlined as `{1, 0}`. Likewise, you should start your application from the command line:

```
env DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=slow.dylib DYLD_FORCE_FLAT_NAMESPACE=1 path/to/YourApp.app/Contents/MacOS/YourApp
```

This will slow down every read calls (even through higher-level APIs). Some read operations will not be affected (e.g. `mmap(2)`), however, and you might want to slow down I/Os on some files but not on others. This later case can be handled by trapping `open(2)` but requires more work.

25ms per read accesses is enough to make any AIR app noticeably slower. Of course, you should adjust this value to your needs.

### Working with a slower file system

Alternatively, you could implement a Fuse plug-in. This is especially easy if you start from LoopbackFS ([C](https://github.com/osxfuse/filesystems/tree/master/filesystems-c/loopback) or [ObjC](https://github.com/osxfuse/filesystems/tree/master/filesystems-objc/LoopbackFS)).

Indeed, you can very easily call `nanosleep(2)` in the [`readFileAtPath:userData:buffer:size:offset:error:`](https://github.com/osxfuse/filesystems/blob/7db23da6b634e1d64bf35416e39e81639306dfce/filesystems-objc/LoopbackFS/LoopbackFS.m#L193) method or [`loopback_read`](https://github.com/osxfuse/filesystems/blob/d9a598638a14f27ba6050aaeee4cae96580a3341/filesystems-c/loopback/loopback.c#L506) function.

Comment: Thanks for your post Paul, I'm not working at that low level, but I'll check into it surely. Thanks again!

Comment: `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES` solution is not so low-level. I did detail the solution so you can very easily test it. It works with a dummy AIR app I had on disk.

Comment: If anyone is interested, the functional code is now also at https://github.com/ain/libsnailio

Comment: The problem here is it won't unfortunately work since the dylib affects `NetConnection` for `NetStream` to be established to local storage, still. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetConnection.html

Answer (score 2):

Well, read and write speeds for the first DVD drives and players were [of 1350 kB/s](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD#cite_ref-32) ([or 1,32 MB/s](http://www.osta.org/technology/dvdqa/dvdqa4.htm)); this speed is usually called "1×" and is the slowest speed that you can find in any DVD drive.

USB 1.1 flash drives have [nominal speed of 12Mbps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#USB_1.x) or [1,5MB/s,](http://forums.anandtech.com/showthread.php?t=1415013) the actual speed is really close to a 1x DVD Drive.

So why don't you copy your image to an old USB 1.1 flash drive and mount it from there? If you don't have any you can find used ones in eBay.

I should also mention that broadband internet connections like ADSL2 or HSPA (3.5G) have actual download speed about 12Mbps which is what you want.